# Labeling and having legends with right colors in the group Matplotlib plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Now let's assume I have a data file example.csv:

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
-42,11,3,L,D
4,21,40,L,Q
2,31,15,R,D
-42,122,50,S,L
```

print(df.head()) of the above is:

```
   first  second  third fourth fifth  sixth
0    -42      11      3      L     D    NaN
1      4      21     40      L     Q    NaN
2      2      31     15      R     D    NaN
3    -42     122     50      S     L    NaN
```

I want to draw the bar plot as a group, where the first and second columns will work as an index. Their different numbers will have different colors.

What I'm expecting is below which I have started working on.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filename = 'example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df.head())

first = df['first']
second = df['second']
third = df['third']
labels = df['third']
x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.35
df.sort_values(by=['third'], axis=0, ascending=False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, third, width, label='Parent 1')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, third, width, label='Parent 2')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
fig.tight_layout()
```

From the bar plot, it is clear that the Y value is from the column called "third", which is exactly what we are getting. But in the grouping, we need to have some modifications to the labeling in the grouping. I have drawn on the figure so you can see what I'm expecting.

1. Each top number on each bar plot will have a different color. FOr example, in the first pair of bars, we have numbers (-42,11). So we need to assign two different colors. But if these numbers on other bars reappear again, these same numbers will have the same color. That means each number will have a unique bar color. The complete list of bar colors can be shown as legends in the top left instead of what we have right now.
2. Another identification will be the bottom of the bars. For example, we have (L, D) in the first pair which are representing the fourth and fifth columns of the data file.
3. I wanted to draw with the descending order of the third column. I applied the command to short the column as descending, but it seems it did not do that in the plot.

df.sort_values(by=['third'], axis=0, ascending=False)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many customization, so I think it's easier with a loop through the rows and plot the bars differently. Also, `sort_values` returns a copy by default, pass `inplace=True` makes it operate inplace:

```
# sort dataframe, notice `inplace`
df.sort_values(by=['third'], axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)

from matplotlib import cm

# we use this to change the colors with `cmap`   
values = np.unique(df[['first','second']])

# scaled the values to 0-1 for cmap
def scaled_value(val):
    return (val-values.min())/np.ptp(values)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')

width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
for i, idx in enumerate(df.index):
    row = df.loc[idx]
    # draw the first
    ax.bar(i-width/2,row['third'], 
           color=cmap(scaled_value(row['first'])),    # specify color here
           width=width, edgecolor='w',
           label='Parent 1' if i==0 else None)        # label first bar
    
    # draw the second
    ax.bar(i+width/2, row['third'], 
           color=cmap(scaled_value(row['second'])),
           width=width, edgecolor='w', hatch='//',
           label='Parent 2' if i==0 else None)

# set the ticks manually
ax.set_xticks([i + o for i in range(df.shape[0]) for o in [-width/2, width/2]]);
ax.set_xticklabels(df[['fourth','fifth']].values.ravel());

ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There is one question. Is there any simple way we can give different colors to the different letters and list them as legends in the top right instead of the "parent1" and "parent 2" . 

Like,  if the first L is yellow, then the second one would be also yellow, and the next letter R would not be blue if there was any color was used as blue already. The reason I was saying because we can list all of the colors as legends in the top right.

Comment: I thought you wanted the **numbers** as colors indicator: *That means each number will have a unique bar color*

Comment: Thanks, that's better I think. In that case, the four number pairs we see  are (-42,11), (4,21), (2,31), (-42,122).  Isn't the only  -42 repetitive? So we should have different colors for all other bars except the -42 number, so we can list all them in the  legends.

Comment: Color as in my code is more of a scale. So 11, 21 are close in the range -42, 122. Of course you can coded them by unique values as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first need to work on the right data structure in the dataframe.   I believe you want the following:

```
df['xaxis'] = df.fourth + ":" + df.fifth
df.groupby('xaxis').agg({'third':'sum','first':'sum'}).plot(kind='bar')
```

it output

```
       third  first
xaxis              
L:D        3    -42
L:Q       40      4
R:D       15      2
S:L       50    -42
```

plots as :

[image: output plot]